# Is it possible to send a custom emoticon in your push notification?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

At our company we have multiple custom emoticons, that are not comprised by the Unicode common ones, is it possible to somehow pass them so they appear in push notifications?.

Comment: As a notification icon? If so yes, it takes a drawable.

Comment: What would be this "notification icon" you speak of. I mean as part of the text, like a smiley followed by text, only that that smiley is custom and not Unicode.

Comment: No, I mean the icon in the notification you get. Although what you can do is save your emoticons in your app and you can display them in the notifications.

Comment: Any guides on how to do that?.

Comment: What i mean is, save your emoticons in your app as drawables. In your push notification send ids for them and display them